# Cartoon show about a boy who is sent to a fantasy world where he encounters the creatures he imagined

Tags: story-identification, anime, isekai

I remember years ago watching this as a child, but I never could finish it. I really want to now, if I can remember the title.

I want to say the first episode is like an anime, I think, but it’s about a male kid who is a runner. Something happens where he retrieves something from his grandfather, I believe. This object he obtains sends him to another world that grants him the power to see his old imaginary creature he made when he was younger. There are also two other characters he meets in this realm that have green hair, I believe. If not both, then the male has it.

Each imaginary creature has a unique ability and element and the green haired one can do plants. Descriptions of the characters are that the main character has a red t-shirt, the other male has a green hair, and the main character's imaginary creature looks somewhat brown and red, like a bear, I think. I also think they’re invisible until they actually want to look.

It was on Netflix for a bit too.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! When exactly did you watch this, "years ago" can mean anything, and we don't know when you were a child ;) And did you watch this on Netflix, or some other platform and happened to notice it was on Netflix?

Comment: Can you rule any shows with a similar premise that aren't the one you're looking for?

Answer (score 8):

Is this ***[Magi-Nation](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1001475/)*** (2007-2010)...?

[image: Promotional art for "Magi-Nation" showing the main characters.]

From the [Magi-Nation Wiki](https://magination.fandom.com/wiki/Tony_Jones#TV_Series):

> Tony Jones was a fifteen-year-old boy from who lived on Earth with his grandfather, Spencer Jones, who was in Tony's care. While running in the middle of a cross-country race, he was mysteriously transported to the Moonlands by Orwin and Evu using a special rock harvested from the Core, which they hoped would summon the Final Dreamer to the Moonlands to help save it from the Shadow Magi, Agram. When Tony arrived, he helped two Magi, Edyn and Strag, defeat two Shadow Magi, and he quickly befriends the allies.

The main character, Tony Jones, is a boy from Earth who wears a red T-shirt and lives with his grandfather. In the first episode, there's a scene where he shows his grandfather a picture of a monster he drew called Furok, and his grandfather gives him a ring with a green jewel in it, which Tony subsequently wears on a chain as a necklace.

Later in the episode, while running in a cross country school race, he's summoned to another world by people who believe he's the prophesised 'Final Dreamer' who will save their world. He meets a red-haired girl named Edyn and a boy named Strag, whose hair is dark purple on top and teal underneath. They can both summon monsters known as Dream Creatures; Strag summons a turtle-like creature named Freep, while Edyn summons a vaguely boar-like creature named Ugger, that has a mane of leaves on its back and can shoot vines through the air.

Tony also figures out how to summon the same Furok creature he drew previously, which looks vaguely like a bear, but with blue and white fur and brown antlers. In this episode, Furok fights another creature that looks somewhat similar, but has red and brown fur.